# PHP Form array has empty values when inserting into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, session

I'm having an issue inserting php form array values into a MySQL table. Right now the form itself pulls worker information from another table to populate the fields and their values. Right now there are only three workers that would populate those fields, however as more workers get added, there could be as many as 40. When I add just the first worker from the form, all the information inserts normally. However, when I add more than one, the title and employeeId fields are blank and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the form:

```
<form method = 'POST' action = 'addworkers.php'>
    <?php
        $sql2    = "select * from workers where companyId = 1";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        $check   = 0;
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $employeeId = $row2["id"];
            $name = $row2["name"];
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="employeeId[]" value="' . $employeeId . '">';
            echo "$name\n";
            echo '<input type = "hidden" value="' . $companyId . '" name = "companyId[]"/>';
            echo '<input type = "hidden" value="' . $jobNumber . '" name = "jobNumber[]"/>';                
            echo 'Site Title : <input type = "text" name = "title[]"/><br/>';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo "$numRows"; ?>"/>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'SEND'/>
</form>
```

Then the addworkers.php code

```
require_once("dbConfig.php");
session_start();
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d");

if (isset($_SESSION['loginname'])) {
    $companyId  = isset($_POST['companyId']) ? $_POST['companyId'] : "" ;
    $jobNumber  = isset($_POST['jobNumber']) ? $_POST['jobNumber'] : "" ;
    $employeeId = isset($_POST['employeeId']) ? $_POST['employeeId'] : "" ;
    $title      = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "" ;

    foreach($title as $key=>$value){
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $query = "insert into `Jobs` (id, companyId, jobId, employeeId, siteTitle, dateAdded) values (NULL,'$companyId[$key]', '$jobNumber[$key]','$employeeId[$key]','$value','$timestamp')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

I changed the echo "Error" line but the output was clear.

It must be a problem with how the array is counted but I'm not sure how to fix it. in the form, if I check the boxes next to each row, all the information is entered into the table properly. If I only check the second and/or third line, it doesn't include the Site Title and the employeeId is reversed.

Here is the output of the form:

```
<form method = 'POST' action = 'insertworkers.php'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="employeeId[]" value="1">Mike
    <input type = "hidden" value="1" name = "companyId"/>
    <input type = "hidden" value="12345" name = "jobNumber"/>
    Site Title : <input type = "text" name = "title[]"/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="employeeId[]" value="2">Steve
    <input type = "hidden" value="1" name = "companyId"/>
    <input type = "hidden" value="12345" name = "jobNumber"/>
    Site Title : <input type = "text" name = "title[]"/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="employeeId[]" value="3">Roger
    <input type = "hidden" value="1" name = "companyId"/>
    <input type = "hidden" value="12345" name = "jobNumber"/>
    Site Title : <input type = "text" name = "title[]"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="3"/>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'SEND'/>
 </form>
```

I also changed the foreach loop to a for loop since the array depth should be the same as all fields will be mandatory

```
require_once("dbConfig.php");
session_start();
$counter   = "".$_POST["count"]."";
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d");

if ( isset( $_SESSION['loginname'] ) ) {
    $companyId  = isset($_POST['companyId']) ? $_POST['companyId'] : "" ;
    $jobNumber  = isset($_POST['jobNumber']) ? $_POST['jobNumber'] : "" ;
    $employeeId = isset($_POST['employeeId']) ? $_POST['employeeId'] : "" ;
    $title      = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "" ;

    for($i=0, $count = count($employeeId);$i<$count;$i++){
        if (!empty($employeeId)) {
            $query = "insert into `customerJobs` (id, companyId, jobId, employeeId, siteTitle, dateAdded) values (NULL,'$companyId', '$jobNumber','$employeeId[$i]','$title[$i]','$timestamp')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: Change your `echo "Error";` to `echo "Error" . mysqli_error($conn);` - is there anything?

Comment: also use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: It would be more helpful to include the actual HTML of the form, not the PHP that generated it.

Comment: open to SQL injection attack, dont use this in actual production

Comment: You're only doing a `foreach` for the one array here, what about the others?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the keys will match up to the other elements of $_POST

Comment: @miken32 `[]` on inputs without a `foreach` *should* throw an error, *no?*

Comment: It should be okay since they're doing `$_POST['companyId'][$key]` unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Why fetch_assoc for one row operation.? Also why companyid [ ] in input ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the html output of the form and I changed the foreach loop to a for loop